# How to handle Angular page refresh with security in mind

Tags: angular, authentication

The scenario I'm trying to understand/solve for.

1. I have a Angular SPA that prompts a user to login when the app first loads.
2. Once a user logs in successfully, the server returns cookie in addition to CSRF token.
3. the cookie can contain just the sessionID or a JWT token.
4. If the user refreshes the page, the user is prompted to login again as data is lost.

In doing research I've read a few articles such as and a few others.

[- https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/)
 [- http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/)

In trying to take personal bias of these articles out the equation, what I've gathered for security reasons is as follows

- to avoid XSS attacks, the session ID should never be made available to the client side javascript. this is typically done via the HttpOnly flag on the cookie that stores the session id or JWT token.
- while you can store a token or session id in session storage, this then becomes accessible via javascript which can lead to vulnerabilities from XSS.

If the cookie storing the sessionid or gwt token is marked as 'HttpOnly' and HttpOnly information is not available via Javascript/Typescript/Angular

- What is the accepted approach for handling page refreshes in single pages app, to determine that this user already has a session?

Once the Angular app loads when the page refreshes, since I can't check for the presense of an HttpOnly cookie, how can I check if this user has previously already logged, and thereby avoid prompting for login?

or is using session storage to maintain the session id the only option here to address this problem.

Any clarity that can be provided on this topic is appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.
While your app loading, it should make request to server e.g. '/getUser', browser adds all cookies to request, BE decides based on these cookies if user logged in or not and respond.
Based on response your app decides to show login or not.

Comment: Thank you. I'd seen some suggestions elsewhere for taking this approach, but was wondering if there was any other way to avoid the extra HTTP request. I'll move forward with this. thanks again.